# Technical reason for no support in lowercase searches in firebase

Tags: firebase

There is currently no support for lowercase searches in Firebase. The best way to handle this would be store the lowercase string along side the original string and then query the lowercase string instead.

But what is the technical reason behind this? Why can't I do an insensitive query?
Is there a chance that this will be implemented someday?

Comment: The first statement is not accurate. I get what you're asking but Firebase does support lower case searches, just not traditional case insensitive searches, as you mentioned. Performing a case insensitive search requires logic; i.e. knowing to search for 'A' *OR* 'a' and Firebase nodes do not contain logic of any kind, so there's no computing involved which is one of the reasons it's so darn fast - it just raw data. So, what's the issue with storing a lower case version of the string, and... to prevent the question from being closed, do you have a specific coding issue we can help with?

Comment: @Jay Thank you for your answer. You are absolutely right, i formulated my question wrong, but you still understood what I meant. There is no problem about storing duplicate data. As a beginner in software development I was just interested in the technical background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jay said in the comments: Performing a case insensitive search requires logic; i.e. knowing to search for 'A' OR 'a' and Firebase nodes do not contain logic of any kind, so there's no computing involved which is one of the reasons it's so darn fast - it just raw data.